# Silverstripe 4 HTMLField (TinyMCE) is stripping inline style attributes on Save/Publish

Tags: silverstripe, tinymce-4, silverstripe-4

I am trying to add a style attribute to an img tag in HTMLText markup view. But every time I save or publish, the attribute is stripped.

I found [this documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/forms/field_types/htmleditorfield/) ("Setting options" - about half way down). So tried that in my /app/_config.php file and did a /dev/build:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOption(
  'extended_valid_elements',
  'img[style]'
);
```

After doing the above, img src was stripped. Because according to [this documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements) the tag rules completely replace existing rules for that tag. Which in Silverstripe's case are found in /vendor/silverstripe/admin/_config.php. The point is, this confirms the above config is definitely being used by Silverstripe.

But the style attribute is still being stripped out on save.